# NodeJs Helmet contentSecurityPolicy blocking fonts

Tags: node.js, express, helmet.js

I am not sure why it allows other fonts from google fonts, but it always blocks material icons and fontawesome. I tried writing google fonts in different ways, but it still does not work. I am not sure what is the correct way of writing the domains that are allowed If I set add '*' to the end of the list then google material fonts loads correctly. Please let me know what I am doing wrong, here is my code

```js
const safeToLoadFonts = [
    "'self'",
    'fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons',
    'fonts.googleapis.com/*',
    'fonts.googleapis.com/',
    'googleapis.com/*',
    'googleapis.com/',

    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css',
    'cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css',
    "'unsafe-inline'",
]



app.use(
    helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
        directives: {
            // defaultSrc: ['*', "'unsafe-inline'"],
            // "script-src": ['*', "'unsafe-inline'"],
            // "style-src": ['*', "'unsafe-inline'"],
            "font-src": safeToLoadFonts,
            // "img-src": ['*', "'unsafe-inline'"],
            // "form-action":[ '*', "'unsafe-inline'"]
        },
    })
);
```

I am also getting this error for material icons:

```
The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'font-src' contains a source with an invalid path: '/icon?family=Material+Icons'. The query component, including the '?', will be ignored.
```

I am getting this error for font-awesome:

```
Refused to load the font '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src 'self' <URL> <URL> fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons fonts.googleapis.com/* fonts.googleapis.com/ googleapis.com/* googleapis.com/ <URL> cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css 'unsafe-inline'".
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you omit the two entries

```js
'fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons',
'fonts.googleapis.com/*',
```

from your list?

The first error is a warning that the `?family=Material+Icons` part of the URL will be ignored, therefore this rule only matches `fonts.googleapis.com/icon`.

The rule `fonts.googleapis.com/*` does not match child paths, the asterisk does not have the meaning you seem to assume here.

Rules ending with a slash, like `fonts.googleapis.com/`, [do match child paths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#hosts_values), but since your CSP additionally contains the stricter rule ending in `/icon`, perhaps the stricter one is applied, blocking the child paths that you need.